# How to get the changes reflected when I call a function using Threading Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, multithreading, single-threaded

I am Threading to Call a function and assign values to a Textbox in Asp.net. When I debug it is showing value, but in the Form it is not getting reflected.

Below is my code.

```
 Protected Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAddFile.Click
        Dim newthread As New Thread((AddressOf ThreadMethod))
        newthread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
        newthread.Start()
    End Sub
```

I am calling the ThreadMethod() to assing values to Textbox1. When I debug I see it gets assinged as "test". But at runtime it is showing empty. I tried the same for setting ImageUrl in Image contol and got the same issue.

```
Protected Sub ThreadMethod()
        TextBox1.Text = "test"
 End Sub
```

Please let me know if I have to do anything to make it reflect at runtime in my form

Comment: You simply don't. Refrain from long-running tasks (namely spawning threads) in a web application. Also, in your example, doing this is utterly pointless.

Comment: I am doing it for a OpenFileDialog(). for which it requires me to use  <STAThread()> and it is not updating at runtime

  Protected Sub ThreadMethod()
        Dim obj As New OpenFileDialog()
        If (obj.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then
            Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Image/Jellyfish.jpg"
        End If
           End Sub

Comment: You can't use OpenFileDialog in ASP.NET - that is for desktop applications.  Check out <asp:fileupload>